# MSG_WAITALL Flag in D

Tags: sockets, d, recv

Is there a way to call receive() on a Socket with the MSG_WAITALL flag, in D? I checked the source but there does not appear to be an enum for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like phobos doesn't define it, but druntime does, so you can cast the value to SocketFlags:

```
// on posix
import core.sys.posix.sys.socket;
receive(buffer, cast(SocketFlags) MSG_WAITALL);

// on windows
receive(buffer, cast(SocketFlags) 0x08 /* MSG_WAITALL, number found on msdn */);
```

this is a bit hackish, but if you look at the source, you can see the flags is just casted back to int when passed to the low level `recv` anyway, so it should work without a problem.